# Check if the value of field is at List which stored as report's parameter

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I need to use an expression like `in array` function.
I have a array parameter in JasperReports' report, Declared like this `param1` and its class is `java.util.List`

I want to use an expression in `print when expression`.The expression should check the fields in that array. I tried this code `{IN,$F{query_id},$P{param1}}` but no use. `$F{query_id}` This the filed to check with array. Is there any way to check values in array?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use ***[List.contains(Object)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#contains(java.lang.Object))*** method.

#### Sample

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="List contains sample" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" whenNoDataType="AllSectionsNoDetail" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20">
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="One Empty Record"/>
    <parameter name="list" class="java.util.List">
        <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA[Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3)]]></defaultValueExpression>
    </parameter>
    <parameter name="valueToFind" class="java.lang.Integer">
        <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA[5]]></defaultValueExpression>
    </parameter>
    <title>
        <band height="79" splitType="Stretch">
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="180" y="10" width="200" height="30">
                    <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$P{list}.contains($P{valueToFind})]]></printWhenExpression>
                </reportElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["I'm visible if value at list"]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </title>
</jasperReport>
```

#### Output result

If the value is present at *List* (for example, 3 for List {1, 2, 3}) the result will be:

[image: JSS, textField is visible]

in other cases (value not found at List) the result in *Jaspersoft Studio* will be (the *textField* is hidden):

[image: JSS, textField is invisible]

In your case the valid expression will be like this:

```xml
<printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$P{param1}.contains($F{query_id})]]></printWhenExpression>
```

Comment: But i cant pass that array parameter in jasperserver :(